# difference between chromedriver.exe and selenium-chrome-driver.jar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know the difference between `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` and `chromedriver.exe`

My friend is able to get the chrome browser launched without specifying the location of `chromedriver.exe` in his script/chromedriver initialization, and she has mentioned `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` in `pom.xml`, does this make any difference. If so then how?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand how Selenium communicates with the browser.

When you write selenium tests, you write code in the language of your choice using the client code bindings.  This code then talks to the relevant driver binary that is run inside the browser as a plugin using the JSON wire protocol.

So the interaction is:

[image: Architecture Overview]

Selenium has a client API which details all of the commands you can send over the JSON wire protocol, it then has a series of pieces of code that allow it to interact with specific driver binaries.  So in your case the `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` has the code that is specifically used to interact with the chrome driver binary.  If you were talking to the gecko driver binary, you would need to use `selenium-firefox-driver.jar`.  Each driver binary that targets a specific browser has an associated jar that contains the code required to talk to the relevant driver binary.

For this to work you need all elements, so to be able to drive Google Chrome with Webdriver you will need to have the `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` and the `chromedriver.exe` binary.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed explanation, it serves my purpose. Such an in depth knowledge you have. I appreciate.

Comment: @Ardesko, can you put some more light on a scenario where, you are not specifying the location of your binary(chromedriver.exe) in any of your configuration class but still chrome browser is getting launched successfully. infact I have removed all related environment variables, but still chrome browser is getting launched. I have verified this with firefox as well as chrome, as both are getting launched.

Comment: By default selenium will use the env variable `webdriver.<browsername>.driver` to locate the driver binary.  In this case the most likely explanation is that you have installed chromedriver on your machine and somewhere there is an env variable called `webdriver.chrome.driver` set that indicates the location of the chromedriver binary.  If you type `env |grep webdriver` into a terminal it should show you any webdriver env variables that have been set.

Comment: to be clear you don't need to set these env variables in code (in fact you shouldn't, setting them in code is the same as hard coding a path to the driver binary in code and defeats the whole object of the env variable).

Answer (score 0):

So `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` is more or less just a ZIP file that can consist of anything.

It would be best to reference the location of the `chromedriver.exe` to launch Chrome.

I believe there isn't much of a difference though if you wanted to use the `.jar`, you would need to extract `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` and reference the `chromedriver.exe` from within there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can you please put more details about these two things separately. What is the significance of selenium-chrome-driver.jar and chromdriver.exe, what would happen if we remove any of them. Separate significance/contribution of each.

Comment: So in a nutshell, when kicking off a Selenium project, there are multiple dependencies you may need to use. For example: `selenium-api, selenium-remote-driver, gson, guava` etc. instead of manually adding these dependencies to the `pom.xml` you can reference the `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` and it will pick up all these dependencies. On the other hand you have `chromedriver.exe` which is the dependency for you to run Selenium Chromedriver. This is a standalone executable and has no other dependencies associated with it unlike the `.jar` file mentioned earlier.

Comment: Finally, if you remove `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` then you will not be able to access the dependencies within that `.jar` file to use within your project. This will mean you need to reference your dependencies in your pom.xml yourself. If you remove `chromedriver.exe` you will not be able to launch ChromeDriver **but if** your `.jar` file holds `chromedriver.exe` within it then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` does not contain the chromedriver driver binary.

Comment: @Ardesco Apologies, I meant it can contain the ChromeDriver.class

Comment: That makes more sense :)